# installing comicsans to TeX Live, Windows

Tags: fonts, packages, installing, texlive, windows

I need help to install the `comicsans` package and the fonts. My system is TeX Live 2011, and Windows 7. Below is what I did:

1. Copied `comic.ttf` and `comicbd.ttf` in
   `C:\texlive\texmf-local\fonts\ttf`. (I created the `ttf` directory.)
2. Copied `dvips`, `tfm`, and `vf` directories from the `comicsans.zip` to `C:\texlive\texmf-local\fonts`.
3. Ran `mktexlsr` to update the file name database.
4. Copied `comicsans.dtx` and `comicsans.ins` in `C:\texlive\texmf-local\tex\latex\comicsans`. (I created the `comicsans` directory.)
5. Ran `tex comicsans.ins` in `C:\texlive\texmf-local\tex\latex\comicsans`.
6. Ran `mktexlsr` to update the file name database.
7. Ran `updmap-sys --enable Map=comicsans.map`.
8. Ran `mktexlsr` to update the file name database.

Using TeXworks, I tested it with:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{comicsans}
\renewcommand{\sfdefault}{comic}

\begin{document}
This is a text.
\end{document}
```

and it did not work. No font change, no error message.

Did I make any mistake, or miss any step? I believe some of the above steps are unnecessary, which one?

Comment: Unless it is going inside a cartoon, let me just say thank god it's not working! `;-)`

Comment: I assume you are using XeTeX or LuaTeX? You should probably specify which one. Also: Dear sweet dog, why?

Comment: I am using `pdflatex`. Of course I don't use comicsans for articles. It is actually for presentation slides, using beamer. Anyway, I want to see my slides in comic sans; please help the installation.

Comment: The decision to use LaTeX/beamer for your presentations might have something to do that you are interested in high quality output and a professtional presentation. However, your choice of font is not optimal see [this article](http://sixrevisions.com/graphics-design/comic-sans-the-font-everyone-loves-to-hate/) mentions some reasons why and lists possible alternatives. Most important reason here: It looks unprofessional.

Comment: This is a joke, right??

Comment: Off-topic : There is no single font that has resisted this much of hate and still around. The reason why it is around is because it is a damn good font, though heavily misused. I feel the same to Apple products or [Helvetica font](http://www.swiss-miss.com/wp-content/uploads/2009/09/d8a5033cb029c5c30d2a93d402def1ddba97582d_m.png) which introduces unnecessary formalism, but can not deny their design is beautiful. Hence, this question demands an answer. I use Miktex so I wish I could answer. I can feel the hate. Bring it on :P

Comment: The single biggest reason to avoid this typeface is the reaction you are seeing now. It doesn't matter one jot if it's a good typeface of not, the fact is that an alarmingly large segment of your audience will hate it do strongly that they'll spend the entire presentation not listening and rhythmically clenching their hands. You may get lynched...

Comment: Sorry, that initially got put in as an answer. Got confused on my iPhone...

Comment: @percusse Papyrus.

Comment: Whilst I loathe comic sans as much as the next person, we should still try to help, here.  (And I'm pleased to see that despite the comments, no-one's actually voted against the question.)

Comment: See now also my answer: [Installing the comicsans package to MiKTeX](http://tex.stackexchange.com/a/79805/9237).

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Your steps for installing the font appear to be correct. You get no font change in your sample document because you're defining ComicSans as the default "sans serif" font, but you aren't choosing that font family.

```
\begin{document}
Somebody would say that this \textsf{Hello world} printed
with a fancy font is awful.
\end{document}
```

If you want the font to be used throughout the document, redefine `\rmdefault` or say

```
\usepackage{comicsans}
```

This regards the technical part. Now a comment.

Don't use ComicSans other than for strips or particular short text. It's *not* a font designed for continuous reading and it will probably annoy your audience during a presentation or, in the worst case, make them laugh.