# Installing comicsans to TeX Live, macOS

Tags: fonts

I am trying to install comicsans following http://www.tug.org/fonts/fontinstall.html and I also looked at [installing comicsans to TeX Live, Windows](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/34850/installing-comicsans-to-tex-live-windows), but it shows

```
pdfTeX error: pdflatex (file comic.ttf): cannot open TrueType font file for reading
Check the TeX log file for more information
```

when compiling the test file

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{comicsans}

\begin{document}
This is a text.
\end{document}
```

I tried to run `tex testfont` for some tfm files and it seemed fine.

This `comic.ttf` file feels mysterious to me. Do I just download the ttf file somewhere and put it in the direction like the post above for Windows?

Answer (score 2):

I suggest to use either `LuaLaTeX` or `XeLaTeX`: That way you can simply load existing `.ttf` and `.otf` fonts without bothering with `LaTeX`'s font handling. Provided you have "Comic Sans MS" installed, this worked for me:

```
\documentclass{standalone}
\usepackage{fontspec}
\setmainfont{Comic Sans MS}

\begin{document}

\large Oh, woe is me!

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Even easier, if you don't actually need Comic Sans, is to use the somewhat similar _Chalkboard_ which is already installed on Macs. Load with `\setmainfont{Chalkboard}` as above and use Lualatex/Xelatex.